# Ignoring errors in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I want JMeter ignore an error. That request error is expected and is part of our session initiation protocol. Can't find a way to hide that error from be displayed on stats etc.

In other words: One of my SOAP samplers return an error (401, authentication thing) and that is expected. That *is* request error, yes, but not an error to report really.

Is that possible in JMeter to hide such errors somehow and/or exclude them from the test result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two options:

1. Reconfigure where you've placed your Listeners, so the request is effectively omitted from results.
2. Use a BeanShell PostProcessor to write a short beanshell script to change the status from "fail" to "pass" if the code is 401.

```
if (prev.getResponseCode() == "401") { 
    prev.setResponseOK(); 
}
```

[image: picture illustration of option2]

Comment: Really good options, thanks! I'll try and comment here if they work for me or not.

Comment: The second option works for me.
I've added following BSF PostProcessor (javascript) directly after guilty sampler: 
if (prev.getResponseCode() == "401") {
  prev.setResponseOK();
}

Comment: I had to write `if (prev.getResponseCode().equals("401")) { prev.setResponseOK(); }` to make it work.

Answer (score 36):

You can also add a Response Assertion bellow the request and check the "Ignore Status" flag.

Comment: This is actually how it should be done, and I was about to reply until I found this. +1

Comment: To get this to work I also had to change the Response Field to Test to Response Code instead of Text response since my response data was null.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Adagios.

I was looking how to test authorization failure to restful web service. So, your solution really helped me.

I configured HTTP request and HTTP Authorization manager with wrong username. It is expected to fail. Then, I added Response Assertion with Text Response and Contains "HTTP ERROR 401". I also marked Ignore Status, so the failure (because of wrong username ) from HTTP Request is dropped. So, I'd see only failure from Response Assertion in Assertion Results.

Answer (score 0):

I coudn't find a solution for this but if the result is always 401, why not omitting this sampler from the test?

You may exlude this sampler from the results manually.

Comment: I can't omit the sampler, I have to send this request to the server. Yeah, parsing the result file with some custom script and remove "junk" should work, but this is the last option, I'd like to avoid this if possible.